# Unresolved Gluu Oxd dependency in Sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, gluu

I am working on Sbt project with play-framework and added the following gluu-oxd dependency in Build.sbt file :

```
resolvers += "Gluu repository" at "http://ox.gluu.org/maven"
libraryDependencies += "org.xdi" % "oxd-java" % "2.4.4.Final"
libraryDependencies += "oxd.play.java" % "oxd-play" % "2.4.4-FINAL"
libraryDependencies += "org.xdi" % "oxd" % "2.4.4.Final"
```

Ref: https://gluu.org/docs/oxd/2.4.4/framework/play/

Now I am getting the following issue when I compile the project:

```
   [warn]  :: oxd.play.java#oxd-play;2.4.4-FINAL: Gluu repository: unable to get resource for oxd/play/java#oxd-play;2.4.4-FINAL: res=http://ox.gluu.org/maven/oxd/play/jav
    a/oxd-play/2.4.4-FINAL/oxd-play-2.4.4-FINAL.pom:
    [warn]  :: org.xdi#oxd;2.4.4.Final: Gluu repository: unable to get resource for org/xdi#oxd;2.4.4.Final: res=http://ox.gluu.org/maven/org/xdi/oxd/2.4.4.Final/oxd-2.4.4.
    Final.pom: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderE
    xception: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    [warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
    [warn]          org.xdi:oxd-java:2.4.4.Final (F:\Project\Master\OxdTest\build.sbt#L9-10)
    [warn]            +- default:oxdtest_2.12:0.1
    [warn]          oxd.play.java:oxd-play:2.4.4-FINAL (F:\Project\Master\OxdTest\build.sbt#L10-11)
    [warn]            +- default:oxdtest_2.12:0.1
    [warn]          org.xdi:oxd:2.4.4.Final (F:\Project\Master\OxdTest\build.sbt#L11-12)
    [warn]            +- default:oxdtest_2.12:0.1
    [error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.xdi#oxd-java;2.4.4.Final: Gluu repository: unable to get resource for org/xdi#oxd-java;2.4.4.
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct issue seems to be what's in the error message "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". In other words, JVM is not trusting the SSL certificate provided by https://ox.gluu.org/maven/ whose root CA seems to be "DST Root CA X3".

If you're not using the latest OpenJDK JDK8 or Oracle JDK 8, maybe trying those would be a good start.